# Nested elements and directives

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I got an workaround here and need some help. It is a tree of categories. Some categores can be chosen by a checkbox.

I thougt the cleanest way to do that is via direction. On a `<li kw-category-node>` element put a `on('click', function())` handler, which then does the choosing work (add object to data etc.).

So I came up with this HTML

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="category_renderer.html">
   <div ng-if="true == true" ng-mouseenter="over = true" ng-mouseleave="over = false">
       <input type="checkbox" 
            ng-model="assignedCategories[category.category_id]"
            ng-if="category.childs.length == 0"
            ng-click="toggleCategory(category)">
        </input> {{ category.name }} 
        <a href ng-if="over" ng-click="categories.remove(category)">
              <small> <i class="fa fa-times"></i> Entf </small>
        </a>
  </div>

  <ul class="list-unstyled">
         <li ng-repeat="category in category.childs"
             ng-include="'category_renderer.html'"
             kw-category-node>
         </li>
  </ul>
</script>

<ul class="list-unstyled" kw-category-tree>
     <li ng-repeat="category in categories.tree"
         ng-include="'category_renderer.html'"
         kw-category-node>
     </li>
</ul>
```

And a directive like that

```
admin.directive('kwCategoryNode', ['$interval', 'dateFilter',   function($interval, dateFilter) {

function link(scope, element, attrs) {


  element.find('input').on('click', function() {

      alert("wow, what a click!");

  });


}
```

But `element.find("input")` wont give me that input element. Maybe the DOM is not loaded completly or I'm just in tilt.

Thanks

Comment: ng-include="'category_renderer.html'" ?  you should not call in the same template within that template.

Comment: I don't know if you just trimmed your code to try and be short but the directive you wrote will never work, the directive function needs to return an object with a property 'link' pointing to a function. You aren't returning anything, so that will never work.

Comment: why not `ng-click` instead of custom events over element?

Comment: @Dwardu it's just trimmed

Comment: @PankajParkar possible, but I think it's redundant, because I had to rebuild the boolean value of the checkbox in an array. So in my opinion it is clearer to use the status of the DOM object itself than tracking it's value in a separate scope variable.

Comment: The issue still remains.

Comment: your code is really strange.  abstract the directive so that you don't need to nest it in within itself.  maybe divide it into two directives.